# Are these two norms on $C^{1}([0,1])$ equivalent?

Tags: analysis, metric-spaces

I'm considering functions on the interval $[0,1]$ which are continuously differentiable, so in the space $C^{1}([0,1])$.  On this space I want to show whether or not the two norms $\|f\|_{A} = \|f\|_{\infty} + \|f\|_{1}$ and $\|f\|_{D} = |f(0)| + \|f'
\|_{1}$ are equivalent.

Note that $\|f\|_{\infty}$ is defined as the supremum of $|f|$ on the interval $[0,1]$ and that $\|f\|_{1}$ is defined as the integral of $|f|$ between $0$ and $1$.

I have proved that $\|f\|_{A}$ is equivalent to $\|f\|_{\infty}$ and also that $\|f\|_{D}$ is not equivalent to $\|f\|_{1}$.

I tried showing that $\|f\|_{A}$ is not equivalent to $\|f\|_{D}$ but could not do this, so this leads me to believe they are equivalent.  However I also could not show they are equivalent.  Any hints?

Thanks.

Comment: Note that ||f||∞ is defined as the supremum of |f| on the interval [0,1] and that ||f||1 is defined as the integral of |f| between 0 and 1. Both are well known norms.
Also f ' is the first derivative of f.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The uniform norm is bounded by the D norm but not vice versa. Consider a sequence of sine waves scaled so that the frequency increases very rapidly and the amplitude converges slowly to 0.

Comment: Yes you are, although I would put another $2\pi$ between the brackets to make sure that the behaviour at the boundary is predictable. The D norm is (up to a term $|f(0)|$ which is 0 anyway for those sinuses) the integral of the absolute value of the derivative of f. The derivative of $f_n$ is $n\cos(2\pi n^2x)$ so its absolute integral increases linearly with $n.$

Comment: Thank you a lot :D although you wrote your derivative wrong i understand what you mean

Comment: Yep there's a factor $2\pi$ missing, I was at a party last night.